# Reverse scrolling with keys (not mouse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I wanna make a progressive scrolling page in the same time of a 3D world navigation. Then I have to press UP key to go through and scroll down in the same time. I wan't to know how I can configure my page with keyboard command to scroll down with UP key et scroll up with DOWN key. I think I can do that in pure JS but I tried in Jquery to begin : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/grm6j26f/)

I tried something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    iScroll = iScroll + 1000;

    $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: iScroll
          }, 1000);
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 38) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: iScroll
          }, 1000);
        }
    });
}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you are listening to keyup events on the element with id `#search`, it's more common to listen on the window as it let's you catch the event globally (anywhere on the page).  The setInterval is also unnecessary you can remove that and update iScroll before doing the actual scroll instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      // Scroll to the current scroll position - 1000
      iScroll = -1000;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
      // Scroll to the current scroll position + 1000
      iScroll = 1000;
    }
  });

  // Check where to scroll to
  setInterval(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + iScroll
    }, 1000);
    // Reset iScroll so that we don't keep scrolling automatically
    iScroll = 0;
  }, 1100)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wgm1gtx6/

Comment: Wow, too fast, thank you ! I'll try to make that smoother now.

Comment: The problem is I can't stay pressing the key and the command repeat, have I a solution to make it continuous ?

Comment: @FlorianFromager see edited answer, guess it's what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you Mathias